# firefox table border color problem

Tags: firefox

```
     <table align="center" width="80%" border="1" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#95F8FD">
           <tr>
<th width="7%" rowspan="2" align="center">&nbsp;</th>
<th colspan="3" align="center">&nbsp;</th>
<th width="6%" rowspan="2" align="center">&nbsp;</th>
<th colspan="2" align="center">&nbsp;</th>
<th width="30%" rowspan="2" align="center">&nbsp;</th>
<th width="5%" rowspan="2" align="center">&nbsp;</th>
 </tr>

 </table><br>
```

border color is not showing correctly in firefox with this html block.but it works fine with chrome and IE.what's the problem with firefox?

Answer (score 0):

You aught to use CSS for styling.  With the exception of rowspan and colspan,  just about all the other attributes you've used are deprecated.